# Have anyone seen golden arch at Gandi Kshetra?

Tags: ramayana, maya, pilgrimage

Have anyone seen golden arch built by vayu for Rama, at Gandi Kshetra, British officer Thomas Monroe has apparently seen? Is it visible to those who're turiya?

Comment: What is meant by "who are Turiya" .. You use it in many of your posts. Turiya is a state FYI.

Comment: @Rickross Turiya Your Soul summed up in to Paramatma. This situation is gained after When Person goes into samadhi.

Comment: I know what Turiya is. But it is not correct to say "who are Turiya" because Turiya is a state of consciousness whereas who refers to persons.  @user17854

Comment: Aham brahmasmi   should have written who have attained, although original natural pure state of brahmanas is turiya.